# individual elements of string are not getting in cout

Tags: c++

I am tring to compare elements of string but in my code it is not giving any value to the elements.
When i am using cout in line 7,it is not showing anything.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/richie-rich/problem

```
string highestValuePalindrome(string s, int n, int k) {
int c=0;
vector<int> v(n/2,0);
for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
{
    if(c>k) return "-1";
    cout<<s[i];
    if(s[i]!=s[n-1-i])
    {
        v[i]=1;
        c++;
        //cout<<c<<" "<<i<<endl;
        if(s[i]>=s[n-1-i]) s[n-1-i]=s[i];
        else s[i]=s[n-1-i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `cout << "Hello!";` before line 7, and see how many `Hello!`s you get. I'm betting `n` is `0`, or `c` is already greater than `k`. Your `cout << s[i]` is never executed because either the loop doesn't start or it exits early.

Comment: How's this function being called?

Comment: @Wander3r https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/richie-rich/problem

Comment: @anitashrivastava don't post code in a comment. It's illegible.

Comment: as you have got the source of the code. for n=4, "Hello!" was called 2 times

Comment: Change `cout<<s[i]` to `cout<<s[i] << "***\n";`This has nothing to do with solving the palindrome problem. You're chasing what appears to be an output buffering issue.

Comment: Calling the function with `highestValuePalindrome("3445",4,1);` did print `3` and `4` for me.

Comment: but even if i change the cout i am unable to compare elements.

Comment: **cout<<s[i] << "***\n"** gives output as ***

Comment: Where is the rest of the function?